# Unable to connect to a migrated Access database on SQL Server as another user: SQL server Error 4060

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, database-connection, connection-string

I have an Access DB that I migrated to SQL server recently. The SQL server is on a Windows server. Now I can work normally with the SQL database but when others log into the same windows server with their credentials they are not able to access the database. As soon as they open Access frontend they get an error saying failed connection. Now I created an ODBC connection string(File DNS) and gave it to the other users in the network but they still are not able to connect to the database. They get an error stating "SQL server connection failed. The server rejected the connection: Access to the selected database has been denied". Can someone please help me to solve this issue so that multiple users can connect to the SQL DB without any issues? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hard to know with the limited information. Are you using windows authentication to sql server, or are you using SQL logons? Either should work fine. The other issue to watch out for is what sql driver did you  use to link with?

If you link say using the native 17 ODBC driver, then that is not installed on workstations by default - you have to download and install that driver.

Or, maybe you linked using the long time "legacy" sql driver - that is by default installed on all workstations.

So, it not clear if you using SQL logons, or using Windows authentication for the connection to the database????

If your using windows authentication, then all those other users will require permissions to be granted to the database.

If you using a SQL logon, then that logon would have been saved when you link the table(s), and again it should work for all users. Its quite common to create ONE logon on SQL server, link using that logon, and thus all users will be connecting to the database using the one same logon id/password.

And, if you linked using a FILE dsn, then zero configeration should be required, since access converts FILE dsn's into what are called dsn-less connections. (the origonal file is not required anymore once you link - you can even delete that FILE dsn, and it will still work).

So, FILE dsn is the best choice, since that dsn is NOT required to be setup on each workstation.

And if you using sql logon's, then make sure you checked the box to remember the password during linking of the tables. That is this check box:

[image]

And note during a re-link the above box does not appear - only on first time linking of table(s).

Comment: D.Kallal Thanks a million. I'm actually using Windows authentication for connecting to Database. I was able to add the user and gave him permission. Now I would please like to have your suggestion and some guidance on this. I would have like 100 users on the network who are going to access the DB. What would be the best way to set this up? Thanks a lot for your help! :)

Comment: using windows authentication then no user cannot even login to their workstation without them having been issued a valid windows logon. So is there a security group that all employees belong to? So you logon to domain controller and give that one security group permissions to the database. Thus all 100 users will now have rights to the database. So when you login to the domain controller all employees and logons are managed by that server. Thus these permissions are not setup in SQL server, but setup on your domain controller computer (domain server). So assign a security group to SQL server

Comment: This assumes that the server where SQL server is running is also part of the domain. Since your using windows security then you don't have or require any SQL server logons, but everyone will use their windows logon - thus you link the tables using windows authentication and no login or password is required. Only require is you add that SQL server permissions on the domain server and access will then work for all logged on users.

Comment: D.Kallal Thanks a million for your answer. I will go over it and try to implement it as see how it goes. Thanks once again for your help and guidance.